# SCCM-like for individuals

Tags: open-source

I need to manage Windows computers for my parents: install software and updates, block certain software, etc. Is there any SCCM (System Center Configuration Manager) and group policy like software (preferably free & open source) that frees me from duplicate work? I'm not asking remote control like TeamViewer, because even with TeamViewer, I still need to perform the same task multiple times.

Comment: You mention Group Policy, why are you not using it?

Comment: It requires tremendous investment in infrastructure: licensing fee for windows server, AD servers, VPN between two houses (yes we have computers at two locations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe take a look at [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com), an open source solution that utilizes PowerShell.

Comment: Also SaltStack, if the machine is behind NAT or has dynamically assigned IP address.